# My code uses `media9` and does most of what is expected, except play the video or audio files!

Tags: media9

The `.jpg`, `.MP3` and `.MP4` files reside in folder …/Files. The code was lifted from `Overleaf` but I cannot get it to play the audio and video files. What is missing? I am running with Windows 10 and MikTeX 2.9.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
An .mp4 file:

\includemedia[width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.6\linewidth,activate=pageopen,
passcontext,
transparent,
addresource=Files/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4,
flashvars={source=Files/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4}
]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Files/Andromeda_Galaxy.jpg}}{VPlayer.swf}

An .mp3 file:
\includemedia[
transparent,
passcontext,
addresource=Files/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3,
flashvars={source=Files/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3},
]{\color{blue}\framebox[0.4\linewidth][c]{Play}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you open the PDF in A-Reader? For testing you could open the `media9` manual in AR. Do the examples therein work? (The FlashPlayer plugin for Firefox must also be installed.)

Comment: @AlexG Not sure what you refer to with `A-Reader`. What I did was compile as `PDFLaTeX`, then inspect the resulting pdf file.

Comment: @AlexG OK, Adobe Reader. Yes, I did.

Comment: @AlexG Evidently I did not have the requisite FlashPlayer installed. All good, problem solved. If you were to present your input as an answer I would be happy to give it a tick.